# jQuery random image

Tags: jquery, html, image, random

I have an index.html page in which I want to show 1 random image from a folder.

I have found a script that I like because I don't have to write each image url. The thing is, I just don't know what to do with this script!

I'm not sure what the "10 + 1" means (max 10 images in the folder?). In the "head", I think I need to link to a `jquery` library. Should the script be in a `.js` file, or can it be simply put in the "body" of the page (or elsewhere)?

**The HTML would be**:

> img src="" class="myClass1" width="100px" height="auto" alt="no image" />

And the script:

```
$('.myClass1').each(function() {

   var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1),
   img = $(this);

   img.attr('src', 'url.com/folder/image_' + num + '.jpg');
   img.attr('alt', 'Src: ' + img.attr('src'));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random` generates a number between zero and one
So this code:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)
```

returns a number between 1 and 10

And your image name will be something like this
image_5.jpg

Comment: But how and where do I put the code? I guess that I have to put a "script" tag before and after the script, but do I put the script in the head, in the body or in a file? Thanks.

Comment: It's good practise to put it in the head (even a src to the JS file instead of the code just in the HTML), then do the work inside a [$(document).ready(..)](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You could put your script tag in the head or body, but we usually put scripts at the end of the body and css links in the head.
Also it's usually better to put your script code in separate files.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Much appreciated.